# What does `grep -n` option mean?

Tags: emacs, grep

When I use `find-grep` in Emacs, this command is appeared.
`find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e {} +`

I searched `-n` option in `man grep`. Why is not there? And What does it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man grep` on my computer:

```
  -n, --line-number
        Prefix each line of output with the line number within its
        input file.
```

Comment: Sorry, I searched it again then I found the explanation. I must have been doing something completely wrong...